# array_merge(array($string), $array) or array_merge((array)$string, (array)$array)

Tags: php, arrays

Question is related with example from here https://www.php.net/array_merge

```
 $beginning = 'foo';
 $end = array(1 => 'bar');

 $result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
```

Usually I use such code `$result2 = array_merge( array($beginning), $end );`

`$end` is already an array. Why need `(array)$end`....

Tested and see the same result.

So question. Is `array_merge( array($beginning), $end )` correct code?

Seems now understood why it is reasonable to use `(array)`

For example `$var2 = array('test2');`

```
 print_r( array($var2) );
```

would be multidimensional array

but

```
  print_r( (array)$var2 );
```

would be the same array as initial.

Comment: no need if its already an array,it'll work with out array

Comment: Is there any difference between `(array)$string` and `array($string)`?

Comment: i dont think thers a difference :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight difference between `array($foo)` and `(array)$foo`, but it won't affect the output.

While `array($foo)` will try to build an array out of `$foo`, obviously returning an array, `(array)$foo` will try to look at`$foo` like it is an array, hence returning an array. Both have the exact same result if your variable is a good candidate for an array, but `(array)$foo` may have a stronger semantic aspect since it exposes your intention of using the variable as an array, rather than building an array out of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) only accepts parameters of type array ***(Since PHP 5.0)***
2. Convert all parameters use typecasting, therefore
3. Add `(array)` before the variable, it's means convert the data type into array, case it is not array.

Note:

If you can ensure all of the variables which used in `array_merge` **ARE** array. You can direct access it, instead of adding the `(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct code. If you are **sure** that the parameter is already an array you don't need the type casting.